# AngularJS bind variable to custom html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to bind a variable in my $scope to a custom HTML attribute like so:

```
<textarea name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="{{translation.form.message}}" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="{{translation.form.validation.message}}"></textarea>
```

although the data binding doesn't work, it just shows up empty in the html. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript that you're using with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including `data` in the name you're using on `$scope`? `data-` is an [HTML5 attribute prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) telling the renderer to ignore the attribute, but JavaScript will see it and expose it after stripping `data-`. I ran into this problem a while ago where I had `data-objects` as an attribute, and it took me a while to remember that `data-` is handled specially.

In your case, you'd have to access `data-validation-required-message=""` as `validationRequiredMessage` in Angular.

Comment: I'm not actually accessing data-validation-required-message in the controller. Just using the {{}} method to bind it in the html.